# Google analytics not working on HTML website

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, vercel, godaddy-api

I want to add Google Analytics to my website. I bought the domain (through GoDaddy) and added my HTML website deployment to it through Vercel. I have followed all the steps to setup Google Analytics for my website, but it is still not showing any data on Google Analytics page. It is not receiving any data from my website.

Please help.
Thanks!

```
  <head>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PZ56BQX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
     <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-248604801-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-248604801-1');
    </script>
  </head>
```

I tried adding the Google Analytics code snippet tag at different locations in my HTML website, but it still didn't work. I am expecting Google Analytics to work properly and provide me live analytics for my website.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to conduct the debugging properly:

1. Make sure you see calls from your pages to GA's `collect?` endpoint. For it, you'll need to go to [the network tab in devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) While there, also make sure you don't have any JS errors in the console.
2. Make sure the `tid` in your request to `collect?` is the same as your property id given that you're trying to use GA UA despite it being deprecated relatively [soon](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en).
3. Now go to the ga property that's in your `tid` and go to the real time report. It shows hits with about 5-10 seconds delay. If you see the hits there, you're good, the connection is established.

Finally, keep in mind that other reports (not real-time) will require time to show any data. That time is up to two days. You will see some data getting in these reports much faster, and usually one day is when all data is there, but Google claims that it can take up to two days. For free accounts. And about 4 hours for GA360 accounts.